# grails - using multiple belongsTo, but only one at a time

Tags: grails, grails-orm

If I want to use a domain class, e.g. MoneyTransaction, for two entirely different purposes, i.e.:

1) when a customer places an order

2) when a member gets paid

such that I have something like:

```
class Order {
   static hasMany = [transactions: MoneyTransaction]
}

class Member {
   static hasMany = [payments: MoneyTransaction]
}
```

and

```
class MoneyTransaction {
   static belongsTo = [order: Order, member: Member]
   static constraints = {
      order(nullable: true)
      member(nullable: true)
   }
}
```

and then in essence **only** use one belongsTo/association at a time, is this pretty "standard" usage, or do I need to switch this modeling?  Right now MoneyTransaction has both credit card and ACH payment capabilities, as both apply for orders.  For payments, just the ACH portion will be used.

Comment: i think you want to get rid of the belongs to. otherwise you will have a many to many relationship which i do not believe you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The domain class definitions that you have posted seem correct based on your requirements. One modification that I'd make here would be to add a custom validator to make sure that both order and member are not null at the same time.

```
    static constraints = {

    order(nullable: true, validator: {field, inst -> inst.member || field})
    member(nullable: true)

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, also for providing the extra constraint.