# Multiple BelongTos but one at a time. Save does not cascade to children

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm taking the example from: [grails - using multiple belongsTo, but only one at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638940/grails-using-multiple-belongsto-but-only-one-at-a-time)

```
class Order {
   static hasMany = [transactions: MoneyTransaction]
}

class Member {
   static hasMany = [payments: MoneyTransaction]
}
and

class MoneyTransaction {
   static belongsTo = [order: Order, member: Member]
   static constraints = {
      order(nullable: true)
      member(nullable: true)
   }
}
```

I have a setup similar to those classes, Order, Member, and MoneyTransaction. I am making a call to Member.addToMoneyTransaction(key: value, .... ).

I've used the debugger and I've verified that the addTo operation is creating the MoneyTransaction and it's unsaved. After I call save with failOnError, I'm not getting an error but the payments collection class doesn't persist the save. If I attempt to use the debugger and call save on the individual child it's self, the save is performed without issue.

Why am I not able to get the save able to save the children of the object?

(I'm using Grails 2.4.3)

Comment: How are you testing that the save hasn't occurred?  Are you using flush:true?

Comment: By the time it leaves the service call, the child isn't saved. Also when the page goes to view the same object, there are no children there.